# Behavior of lists in python during assignment

Tags: python, list

I have the following code in python:

```
gates=[16, 16, 24, 24, 24, 27, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 40, 40, 40, 56, 56, 64, 96];
a=gates;
one=a[0];
b=a;
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    b[i]=a[i]/one
```

Now, at the end of this, I get the following as the output of 'b', as expected:

```
>>> b
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6]
```

But I expect that 'a' is unchanged.. but it has changed too.

```
>>> a
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6]
```

And to my surprise, 'gates' has changed too!

```
>>> gates
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6]
```

Any clues on how to retain 'a' and 'gates' intact?
Thanks!

Comment: `a` and `gates` (and `b`) refer to the same list. Do you want to create a copy of the list?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a copy of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
a = gates[:]
b = a[:]
```

these will make a copy of `gates` and `a` lists

Answer (score 3):

All of them are references to the same object, so modifying any one of them will affect all references:

```
>>> gates=[16, 16, 24, 24, 24, 27, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 40, 40, 40, 56, 56, 64, 96];
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(gates)  #reference count to the object increased
2
>>> a = gates
>>> sys.getrefcount(gates)  #reference count to the object increased
3
>>> b = a
>>> sys.getrefcount(gates)  #reference count to the object increased 
4
```

If you want a new copy then assign the new variables to a **shallow copy** using `[:]`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a[0] = 100
>>> a
[100, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

If the list contains mutable objects itself then use [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).